# How do I update the signature of a class in a NuGet package that I'm authoring?

Tags: nuget

I'm developing a small [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FlomsDev.Telegram.ProjectDaidalos). I just deleted a method overload in both versions 1.0.6 and 1.0.7. The method overload is definitely not in my release DLL anymore, but the NuGet package seems to still contain that method overload.

Comment: (if anyone wonders, I'm talking about the overload of AddCommand(Action<blah,blah,blah>, string, CommandType))